# Borders in Firefox scrollbar

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, mate

On my Ubuntu 20.04 installation with Mate as DM, I am facing the annoying problem that the page scrollbar in Firefox seems to have a 1 pixel wide border on the left and right side. Clicking into this border scrolls one page up/down. This is annoying because if I put the window into fullscreen and move my mouse to the right on top of the scrollbar thumb, clicking and dragging does not do what I expect (moving the thumb) but rather scrolling page-wise.

I don't have this issue on a Ubuntu 20.04 installation with xfce, nor on my Mac. I tried different themes, and running firefox with LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0. I started Firefox with a new profile (without addons, configuration changes). No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another hour or two of googling did not find ANYTHING related to this for Firefox, I came to the conclusion that it must be gtk-3 related. Strangely all other apps in Mate do not show this issue, but alas.

By adding ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css file with the following contents this issue goes away (dunno why, and you may want to fiddle with the numbers for the ideal size of the scrollbar):

```
scrollbar slider {
    /* Size of the slider */
    min-width: 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 17px;

    /* Padding around the slider */
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Config taken from https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tweaking-your-scrollbar-settings/16161/2, though it was not related to this issue.